# JQuery Validator and Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have a code in views:

```
def check_username(request):
    if HttpRequest.is_ajax and request.method == 'GET':
        username = request.GET['username']
        if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            print('duplicate')  # have this for checking in console
            return HttpResponse(False)
        else:
            return HttpResponse(True)
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Zero")
```

It takes the request from JQuery and that print('duplicate') works right, printing only when I have duplicate. 
My JS code:

```
 $("#formregister").validate({
        rules: {
            username: {
            required: true,
            remote: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/checkname"
            }  
        },
        messages: {
            username: {
            required: 'you MUST have username',
            remote: 'gogogog'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

"You MUST have username" works properly, but I can't get remote message. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

EDITED:

I use remote incury to to check_username. When I try username "wefefwef" there is in my terminal:

```
[30/Dec/2017 08:29:21] "GET /accounts/checkname?username=wefefwef HTTP/1.1" 301 0 
[30/Dec/2017 08:29:21] "GET /accounts/checkname/?username=wefefwef HTTP/1.1" 200 4
```

If i try DmitryAdmin (already used) i get:

```
duplicate 
[30/Dec/2017 08:32:14] "GET /accounts/checkname/?username=DmitryAdmin HTTP/1.1" 200 5
```

That duplicate shows, that backend get request, but something is wrong with answer.

HTML:

```
<div class="login-page">
    <div class="form">

      <form class="register-form" method="POST" action="{% url 'signup' %}" id = "formregister">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <input class="input" type="text"
                 name="username" placeholder="имя пользователя" maxlength="150"/>

          <input  class="input"  type="text"
                 name="email" placeholder="email"/>

          <input class="input" type="password" id="password1"
                  name="password1" placeholder="пароль"/>

          <input class="input" type="password" id="password2"
                 name="password2" placeholder="повторите пароль"/>

          {% if form.username.errors %}
          <p class="error-message" >Имя пользователя занято или использованы недопустимые символы</p>
          {% endif %}
          {% if form.email.errors %}
          <p class="error-message" >Некорректный или зарегестрированный адрес электронной почты</p>
          {% endif %}
          {% if form.password2.errors %}
          <p class="error-message" >Пароль не совпадает либо слишком легкий</p>
          {% endif %}

          <button type="submit">создать</button>

          <p class="message">Уже зарегистрированны? <a href="#" id ="alogin-reg" for="login-form">Войти.</a></p>
          <p class="message">Забыли пароль? <a href="#" id ="arestore-reg" for="reset-form">Восстановить.</a></p>
      </form>
```

EDITED #2:

```
[30/Dec/2017 09:28:05] "GET /accounts/checkname?username=wepfwe HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[30/Dec/2017 09:28:05] "GET /accounts/checkname/?username=wepfwe HTTP/1.1" 200 4
[30/Dec/2017 09:28:11] "GET /accounts/checkname/?username=Dmitry HTTP/1.1" 200 4
[30/Dec/2017 09:28:12] "GET /accounts/checkname/?username=DmitryA HTTP/1.1" 200 4
[30/Dec/2017 09:28:12] "GET /accounts/checkname/?username=DmitryAd HTTP/1.1" 200 4
[30/Dec/2017 09:28:12] "GET /accounts/checkname/?username=DmitryAdm HTTP/1.1" 200 4
[30/Dec/2017 09:28:12] "GET /accounts/checkname/?username=DmitryAdmi HTTP/1.1" 200 4
duplicate
[30/Dec/2017 09:28:13] "GET /accounts/checkname/?username=DmitryAdmin HTTP/1.1" 200 5
```

Comment: I read your description several times and have a limited idea what you are looking for to do. Rephrase please.

Comment: I need to validate my username while registration. If username exists I need to render message 'gogogog' using JQuery Validator.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#formregister").validate({
    rules: {
        username: {
        required: true,
        remote: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/checkname"
        }  
    },
    messages: {
        username: {
        required: 'you MUST have username',
        remote: 'gogogog'
        data: {
               username: function() {
                return $( ".error-message" ).val();
      }
        }
    }
});
```

try this code
and insted of true/false send string messages in django view

Comment: made it. Check.